# Custom CollectionEditor doesn't serialize to aspx code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, persistence, designer

**Context**

I've been working on a custom collection editor / designer for a custom ASP.Net web control. The web control exposes a strange hierarchy, so a custom editor seemed like the right thing to do to make it easier for developers.

Building ASPX code and using the web control works. In other words, things like `PersistChildren` and `ParseChildren` are taken care of.

The signature of the property in the web control looks something like this:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[Themeable(false)]
[Browsable(false)]
public virtual DimensionsCollection Dimensions { get; internal set; }
```

Note that the property is not public; if it were public, all kinds of things in the designer will go wrong. `DimensionsCollection` is a class that simply inherits `List<Dimension>`. The `Dimension` class itself is nothing fancy, just a thing with some properties.

Just because I think it looks cool, I want to be able to modify the property from an action in the designer. To do that, I implemented a `ControlDesigner` class and added an `ActionList`. One of the actions there is a linkbutton that opens an editor:

```
var editor = new Editors.DimensionEditor(control.Dimensions);
if (editor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{ /* SEE BELOW */ }
```

The editor itself is a windows form that takes a `List<Dimension>` as constructor argument and modifies the collection.

**Problem**

When I use this code, I can see that the editor works and that the control collection is updated in the 'designer' view. If I open the editor multiple times, the state changes, meaning that somewhere in memory the state is updated by the editor.

However, if I go to the ASPX code, I can see that the Dimensions are not there anymore. So, the problem in a nutshell is that I somehow have to tell Visual Studio to write/serialize/persist the property to the ASPX file. (*simple as that...*)

Strangely, I cannot find anywhere how to do this... even though a normal `CollectionEditor` seems to be capable of doing just that (which I cannot subclass unfortunately)

**Some things I tried**

For other properties I noticed you have to use something like this, but this doesn't seem to work. Code was entered at the point marked as 'see below' or in some cases to a helper call in the designer called from that point:

```
PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(base.Component)["Dimensions"];
// use setter with internal property -> no effect
// this.OnComponentChanged(this, new ComponentChangedEventArgs(this.Component, pd, null, newdim)); -> no effect
// use getter to obtain list -> populate that using another list that's created in the editor
```

I can understand why it doesn't work; apparently someone has to tell Visual Studio that the property has changed... I just don't know how to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really a pain to figure out with apparently no sources online that explain how to do this.

Basically you want to use the OnComponentChanging / Changed methods to notify the designer. And apparently the designer uses transactions for the rest of the logic. (My guess is that it has to do with undo/redo behavior). For a normal type this is done automatically when you use the `PropertyDescriptor`, for collections it apparently doesn't wrap the collection which means you have to do it manually.

To solve the issue, you need to create a small method like this in either the `UITypeEditor` or in the `DesignerActionList` class your implementing:

```
private void ChangeAction(List<Dimension> newDimensions)
{
    IDesignerHost host = GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
    PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyControl))["Dimensions"];
    var dimensions = (DimensionsCollection)pd.GetValue(control);

    var trans = host.CreateTransaction();
    IComponentChangeService ccs = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
    ccs.OnComponentChanging(control, pd);

    dimensions.Clear();
    dimensions.AddRange(newDimensions);

    ccs.OnComponentChanged(control, pd, null, dimensions);
    trans.Commit();
}
```

If you're implementing a `UITypeEditor`, make sure to use `context.Instance` from `EditValue` as the control and the given `provider` to lookup the services.